# Hello adding different images to rows in a ListView

Tags: android

i am quite new to android and i was wondering how i could go about adding a listview with different images and text. What i am trying to achieve is a listview with four rows which have a different Icon? I don't know how to set that up using the xml layout provided. should i build this using different multiple linear layout or is there a better way to go about it?.. All the examples i have seen all seem to be using one particular Icon and no much detail of the xml layout. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: do i create different ImageViews for each Icons in the XML file?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of rows you can just use a `LinearLayout` and save yourself some headache.  If you need to have a dynamic number of rows then you need to make a custom adapter for your list.  If you do a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Android+Custom+Adapter), there are a lot of tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: yes. i thought so. but i was just wondering if it was a waste of resources or bad practice of UI optimisation, creating a LinearLayout for every row of ImageView and TextView in the List.

Comment: I agree If you have only four rows you should not use ListView, LinearLayout is enough.

Comment: I was thinking of using the listview because i was wanted to be able to use an ItemClickListener on each rows. can it be possible to use this on the linear layout

Comment: Please, sorry to bother, but is there away i can make the Linearlayout have a ListView look(i mean, with the divided lines between each rows) because when i create the rows in linearlayout, they look really flat. Thank you